# JAS 2.2 and Facelet support jar

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, facelets, jsf-2.2

I am familiar to create simple application using JSF 2.0 in netbeans IDE.

I need to create simple application using JSF 2.2 with Facelet.

What are the jars required to create simple application using JSF 2.2 and Facelet.

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you download Mojarra 2.2, you get only one JAR named: **javax.faces.jar**

i am not familiar with NetBeans IDE, so i will show you how to do it with **Eclipse JEE Kepler**:

**(if you do it as follow, you do not need to download mojarra manually)**

after downloading this version of Eclipse, run it...etc.

now from the Drop Menu

1. -> file -> new -> Dynamic Web Project
2. -> enter your Project Name

   target Runtime: select the Tomcat Directory

   Dynamic Web Module Version: 3

   Configuration: Java Server Faces v2.2 Project

   next
3. -> next, Select the checkbox: generate web.xml ....
4. -> next, JSF Implementation Library:

   at the right side of the select Menu you see an icon for download: click it, wait till you see Mojarra 2.2 ...., select it and install it
5. finish!